# como mostrar un snackbar personalizado desde una clase fragment?

Tags: android-studio, android-fragment

trata de mostrar un snackbar personalizado, ya tengo diseñado su respectivo layout, pero cuando lo ejecuto me sale el siguiente error: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No suitable parent found from the given view. Please provide a valid view.`

Estas son las clases que tengo:

widget_snackbar_error.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/constraintLayout_SnackBarMensajeError"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_default="percent"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_percent=".07"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_default="percent"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="1">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/imageView_contentDescription"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_close_grey50_20dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_default="percent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent=".5"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.05"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_default="percent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent=".05" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtView_MensajeError"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="@string/textView_mensaje_error"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_default="percent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent=".5"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.4"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.45"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_default="percent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent=".7" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

metodo desde el cual es llamado el snackbar:

```
private void mostrarMensajeError(String mensaje){
    View view = getView().findViewById(android.R.id.content);
    Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(view, "", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
    Snackbar.SnackbarLayout layout = (Snackbar.SnackbarLayout) snackbar.getView();
    layout.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    View snackView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.widget_snackbar_error, null);
    ((TextView)snackView.findViewById(R.id.txtView_MensajeError)).setText(mensaje);

    layout.addView(snackView, 0);
    snackbar.show();
}
```

la clase fragment se llama `FragmentRegistrarseCompletarFormulario.java` y su fragmentlayout se llama `fragment_registrarse_completar_formulario.xml`, el metodo mostrarMensajeError(mensaje) esta dentro de la clase fragment `FragmentRegistrarseCompletarFormulario.java`, alguien que me ayude a solucionar este error. Cuando lo paso a un Activity corre bien, pero cuando le paso a una clase fragment sale ese error.

Comment: Y el código del snakbar?

Comment: Claro que sí, los errores son los que ayudan a resolver los problemas. Agrega el código aunque no funcione para poder identificar cual es el problema.

Comment: Cual es el error que te muestra?

Comment: ` java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No suitable parent found from the given view. Please provide a valid view.
        at android.support.design.widget.Snackbar.make(Snackbar.java:181)
        at com.example.CapaUI.Acceso.Registrarse.CompletarFormulario.FragmentRegistrarseCompletarFormulario.mostrarMensajeError(FragmentRegistrarseCompletarFormulario.java:269)
        at com.example.CapaUI.Acceso.Registrarse.CompletarFormulario.FragmentRegistrarseCompletarFormulario.onClick(FragmentRegistrarseCompletarFormulario.java:185)`

Comment: De donde sacas el `android.R.id.content`

Comment: es un atributo que ya viene definido en android studio, pero no te preocupes ya lo arregle.

Answer (score 0):

problema resuelto. Para los que quieren mostrar en Snackbar en una clase fragment aqui les dejo una opcion, posiblemente haya muchas pero a mi me funciono esta:

```
private void mostrarMensajeError(String mensaje){
    Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(getView().getRootView().findViewById(android.R.id.content), "", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);
    Snackbar.SnackbarLayout layout = (Snackbar.SnackbarLayout) snackbar.getView();
    TextView textView =  layout.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
    textView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    View snackView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.widget_snackbar_error, null);

    TextView textViewTop = snackView.findViewById(R.id.txtView_MensajeError);
    textViewTop.setText(mensaje);
    textViewTop.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

    layout.setPadding(0,0,0,0);
    layout.addView(snackView, 0);

    snackbar.show();
}
```